# Type placeholder in Template Literals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

So I was attempting this:

```js
    if(location.href == `${base}/tours`) {
      console.log("in list")
    } else if (location.href == `${base}/tours/${string}`) {
      console.log("in detail");
    }
```

And I get this error:

`'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

`base` is indeed a variable, and `string` I am hoping to just be a placeholder for any string.

I was wondering if it was even possible to have a type as a placeholder in template literals? In the second `if` I am checking for the `baseURL/tours/<any string>`, the `any string` could be `tour-one`, `tour-two`, `tour-three`...

Comment: You're looking at using regular expressions then–that's what it is designed for.

Comment: "*and `string` I am hoping to just be a placeholder for any string*" this doesn't exist. Either use partial string comparisons or regular expressions. There aren't any wildcards.

Comment: Use `location.href.startsWith(base + '/tours/')`

Answer (score 0):

Template literals can only create a single, specific string. They cannot express the concept of "any string".

Instead, use `startsWith`:

```
if (location.href.startsWith(`${base}/tours/`)) {
  console.log("in detail");
}
```

Or use a regular expression:

```
const pattern = new RegExp(`^${base}/tours/(.*)`);
const result = pattern.exec(location.href);
if (result) {
  console.log("in detail");
  // The part matched by `(.*)` will also be available as `result[1]`
}
```

Stepping back, the cleanest solution would be to use a router library that handles these URLs for you. For example, in React you can use [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, you can just use it like

```
type Route = `/tours/${string}`;
```

and then

```
// Should succeed:

goToRoute("/tours/users");
goToRoute("/tours/");
goToRoute("/tours/admin/users");

// Should error:

// @ts-expect-error
goToRoute("users/1");
// @ts-expect-error
goToRoute("http://facebook.com");
```

As you noticed this will replace `${string}` with whatever your string is but it has to start with the `/`.

I just learned this while following TotalTypescript course, so you can get more details about this specific solution from **Matt Pocock** himself [here](https://www.totaltypescript.com/workshops/type-transformations/template-literals/only-allow-specified-string-patterns).

Also, you can get some more info from [Official TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).